# Python converting a space delimited file to csv issue with dates?

Tags: python, regex, file, csv

I need to turn a space delimited file into a comma delimited one. The issue however is the input string contains datetimes which contain a space. The actual input is a lot longer I have shorted it for the purpose of the question. The size is variable length so I cannot hard code the positions of the spaces.

Input:

```
StoreID= 0  JobID= 5429  Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06  Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:15  ObjKey= 0ce0e90a
```

Taget output:

```
StoreID=,0,JobID=,5429,Started=,19/02/2020 12:32:06,Stopped,19/02/2020 13:28:15,ObjKey=,0ce0e90a
```

Currently I am just using line split and replace but this adds commas between the time and date. I was thinking of using regex to try and match digit comma then digit on a second pass but can not get this to work.

```
    line = "StoreID= 0  JobID= 5429  Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06  Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:15  ObjKey= 0ce0e90a"
    tmp = " ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ',')
    output = "StoreID=,0,JobID=,5429,Started=,19/02/2020,12:32:06,Stopped,19/02/2020,13:28:15,ObjKey=,0ce0e90a"
```

**Update**

Here is a copy of one full input line and using @Serge Ballesta's answer. As you can see at the end of the line there are some single space separated fields which are being missed.

```
line = "StoreID= 0  JobID= 5428  Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06  Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:14  ObjKey= 0ce0e90a_5e4d2ac5_1178_28cf  ObjectSize= 125315962691  Written= 125315962691  Read= 0  Cloned= 0  DedupRatio10x= 1501  CompRatio10x= 44  WriteFrag10x= 18  MatchCand10x= 22 MatchHits10x= 19  RunTimeMBps= 3369.000 37.197  ClientTimeMBps= 1091.337 114.828  ClientMessageTimeMBps= 218.814 572.705  ServerTimeMBps= 122.837 1020.179  Bottleneck20%= [ISV_WAIT]  Bottleneck30%= [ISV_WAIT]  Bottleneck40%= [ISV_WAIT]  Clone%= 0.00 0.00  Match%= 14.52 10.70  Store%= 4.95 0.19 Flush%= 0.58 0.36 SeekRead 0"
tmp = " ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ',')
output = "StoreID= 0,JobID= 5428,Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06,Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:14,ObjKey= 0ce0e90a_5e4d2ac5_1178_28cf,ObjectSize= 125315962691,Written= 125315962691,Read= 0,Cloned= 0,DedupRatio10x= 1501,CompRatio10x= 44,WriteFrag10x= 18,MatchCand10x= 22 MatchHits10x= 19,RunTimeMBps= 3369.000 37.197,ClientTimeMBps= 1091.337 114.828,ClientMessageTimeMBps= 218.814 572.705,ServerTimeMBps= 122.837 1020.179,Bottleneck20%= [ISV_WAIT],Bottleneck30%= [ISV_WAIT],Bottleneck40%= [ISV_WAIT],Clone%= 0.00 0.00,Match%= 14.52 10.70,Store%= 4.95 0.19 Flush%= 0.58 0.36 SeekRead 0"
```

Comment: is it space-delimited or tab-delimited file? Is the list of keys (StoreID, JobID, etc.) constants or changing?

Comment: @buran it is space delimited, the keys are constant I believe. The actual file this will run on is 400MB so I've taken the first 10 to test and they look to be constant.

Comment: Your only sample line has *two* spaces between the main items, and only one 'inside' entire strings. Is that correct for the entire document?

Comment: @usr2564301 my bad, yes the file does in fact have two spaces between values, however there are some which have one. I am unable to change the input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input line is correct, the *separators* are a sequence of two spaces, so you could do:

```
output = ','.join(line.split('  '))
```

If it is a sequence of *at least* 2 blank characters you could use a regex:

```
output = ','.join(re.split(r'\s\s+', line))
```

---

For you last line, the separator is a sequence of spaces followed with an uppercase letter. A regex could do the job:

```
line = "StoreID= 0  JobID= 5428  Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06  Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:14  ObjKey= 0ce0e90a_5e4d2ac5_1178_28cf  ObjectSize= 125315962691  Written= 125315962691  Read= 0  Cloned= 0  DedupRatio10x= 1501  CompRatio10x= 44  WriteFrag10x= 18  MatchCand10x= 22 MatchHits10x= 19  RunTimeMBps= 3369.000 37.197  ClientTimeMBps= 1091.337 114.828  ClientMessageTimeMBps= 218.814 572.705  ServerTimeMBps= 122.837 1020.179  Bottleneck20%= [ISV_WAIT]  Bottleneck30%= [ISV_WAIT]  Bottleneck40%= [ISV_WAIT]  Clone%= 0.00 0.00  Match%= 14.52 10.70  Store%= 4.95 0.19 Flush%= 0.58 0.36 SeekRead 0"
output = re.sub(r'\s+([A-Z])', r',\1', line)
print(output)
```

gives:

```
StoreID= 0,JobID= 5428,Started= 19/02/2020 12:32:06,Stopped 19/02/2020 13:28:14,ObjKey= 0ce0e90a_5e4d2ac5_1178_28cf,ObjectSize= 125315962691,Written= 125315962691,Read= 0,Cloned= 0,DedupRatio10x= 1501,CompRatio10x= 44,WriteFrag10x= 18,MatchCand10x= 22,MatchHits10x= 19,RunTimeMBps= 3369.000 37.197,ClientTimeMBps= 1091.337 114.828,ClientMessageTimeMBps= 218.814 572.705,ServerTimeMBps= 122.837 1020.179,Bottleneck20%= [ISV_WAIT],Bottleneck30%= [ISV_WAIT],Bottleneck40%= [ISV_WAIT],Clone%= 0.00 0.00,Match%= 14.52 10.70,Store%= 4.95 0.19,Flush%= 0.58 0.36,SeekRead 0
```

Comment: I've updated the question, this worked however the file does contain some single spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute "dd/mm/yyyy," by "dd/mm/yyyy "

```
output = re.sub(r'([\d]+\/[\d]+\/[\d]{4})\,',r'\g<1> ',output)
```

for Match%=,15.43,11.62,Store%=,5.03,0.22:

```
output = 'Match%=,15.43,11.62,Store%=,5.03,0.22'
output = re.sub(r'([\d]+\.[\d]{2})\,([\d]+\.[\d]{2})',r'\g<1> \g<2>',output)
```

Comment: So this did work to remove the dates, however there are some fields with two values which also get comma separated. Is there a way of doing this for this example: 
Match%=,15.43,11.62,Store%=,5.03,0.22